# convert ážŸáž½áž“ to Unicode

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I use R programming language to produce report.
as data I got from mysql database is something like this: ážŸáž½áž“
anyways to convert to unicode?

Comment: How do you know that's not already unicode? What encoding is it? What encoding does your database use? What value you are expecting? There is simply not enough information here to tell what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].